# Edit Sharepoint shared web part CSS for extra actions

Tags: css, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, customization

Currently I have a web part with some custom CSS. This is a Document Library web part which also contains the link to "Add a new document" below.

[image]

Once I click Add new document I am taken to the upload document page. Is there any way to have the upload document section displayed on the same page or is there an easy way to custom style the upload document page for just this library only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the upload page is also a web part page which hosts a list form web part. You can add the web part to any page and add custom CSS to that page, even using Content Editor WP. The problem is that the Add new document link always points to the page that is designated as the New form page of the list, you can change this setting using SharePoint Designer in 2007 (it's even simpler in 2010).